# Download files from FTP using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I try to download files from remote FTP server to my local folder and unzip it using `ftp` module:

```
var unzipper = require('unzipper');
var Client = require('ftp');

var c = new Client(); //init ftp client
var connectionProperties = { 
    host: "ftp.someurl.com",
    user: "user",
    password: "past",
};

c.connect(connectionProperties);

c.list('ftp/folder',function (err, list) {
  list.map((element,i)=>{
    c.get(element.name, function (err, stream) { //get file from ftp
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.pipe(unzipper.Extract({path:'local/folder/'+element.name})).promise().then((i)=>{
        console.log('File '+element.name+' unziped');
      })
      stream.once('close', function() {
        c.end();
      });
    })
  })
  if(i==element.length-1) {
    console.log('Done!');
    c.end();
  }
})
```

But for many files in `list` I have connection errors:

```
Error: Unable to make data connection
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node_test/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:935:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at Object.cb (/Users/user/node_test/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:575:18)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node_test/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:117:20)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at Parser._write (/Users/user/node_test/node_modules/ftp/lib/parser.js:59:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (/Users/user/node_test/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:273:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
```

Any ideas? Maybe somebody know more useful way?

**UPDATE**

Now I try to use `async.mapLimit` for files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var unzipper = require('unzipper');
var async = require('async');
var Client = require('ftp');

//FTP Init
var c = new Client(); //init ftp client
var connectionProperties = { 
  host: "ftp.server.com",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass",
};

c.connect(connectionProperties);

var folders=['folder1','folder2','folder3','folder4','folder5'];

//Get folder file list
var listFile = function(ftp_files_folder){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    c.list(ftp_files_folder,function (err, list) {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve(list)
    })
  })
}

//Get and unzipfiles from all folders
async.mapLimit(folders, 1, function(folder, callback){
    var local_folder=__dirname+folder;
    var ftp_files_folder=folder;

    listFile(ftp_files_folder).then((paths)=>{
        console.log('Checking files for: '+folder);
        async.mapLimit(paths, 1, function(file, callback){
            var file_type='.xml';
        var ftp_file_path=ftp_files_folder+'/'+file; //get ftp path to file
        var local_file_path=local_folder+'/'+file; //get local path to file
        var local_subfolder=local_file_path.split(file_type).shift(); //get local subfolder name
        if(!fs.existsSync(local_subfolder)){
            c.get(ftp_file_path, function (err, stream) {
                if(err){
                console.log('Error getting ' + element)
                callback(err)
              }else{
                stream.pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: local_subfolder})).on('finish', ()=>{
                      console.log('==File '+file+' unziped==');
                      callback();
                  })
              }
            })
          } else {
              callback();
          }
      }, function(err, res){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log('Updates for '+folder+' complete');
        callback();
      })
    })
}, function(err, res){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  if(res.length==folders.length) c.end();
  console.log('Done!');
})
```

Comment: The examples available for `node-ftp` are **quite different** from your above: https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp . Sounds like you're calling **list** before the connection is available. There is a `ready` event fired from the client instance, you should wrap your list inside it. Also, I would add a **timeout** between them. Also, why are you using `map`?

Comment: This construction work too. But sometimes I fave connection error. What function for list array more then useful? forEach?

Comment: It looks like this would try to download all the files in the folder simultaneously.  Do you have enough connections for that?  Does it fail on the first iteration or further through the list of files?

Comment: @James The connection error occurs after downloading multiple files. Randomly. Sometimes after 5-6 files. Sometimes after 15 files. Sometimes all file downloaded.
But in final script I need download over 500 files.

Comment: @DanMishin I don't think it's a good practice to process **Async** operations in **Map** callbacks. Think about it: you're executing **a lot** of async requests consecutively. Besides, `map` **overrides** array values returning a **new** transformed array, this is now what you want. You should do **an asynchronous loop**, either sequential, either parallel with a maximum amount of calls, so that you won't make too many parallel calls.

Comment: @briosheje Now I use `async.mapLimit` (code in the update section of topic). Work more better I think